# nodejs getstream.io delete user feed and all linked activities

Tags: javascript, node.js, getstream-io

i have a problem to delete a user feed and all linked activities.
i have a user flat data and i create all users with this structure. if my first user "pippo" post a different activities like: photo, comments, likes ecc.
when i delete the pippo feed i remove all his activities easily but i cant remove the activities that the other users did against Pippo

this is the event posted by the user: pippo

```
   [ { actor: 'pippo',
       created: 38573473728,
       foreign_id: 'idddd',
       id: '3b3dd5b8-e8a0-11e6-8080-800005cdbcc2',
       object: 'event: 1',
       origin: null,
       target: null,
       time: '2017-02-01T17:02:36.769836',
       to: [],
       verb: 'Event' } ] }
```

and this is the like posted by different users to the pippo event

```
   [ { actor: 'topolino',
       created: 38573473728,
       foreign_id: 'kjhkjhkj',
       id: 'a70a22d8-e8a0-11e6-8080-80001f8eb880',
       object: 'event: 1',
       origin: null,
       target: null,
       time: '2017-02-01T17:05:37.624956',
       to: [],
       verb: 'like' } ] }
```

if i use this command

```
client.delete({
    url: "feed/user/" + "pippo",
    signature: user.signature
}, function (e, r) {
    //console.log(e);
    console.log(r);
});
```

as I said before, the user pippo is deleted but the likes still remaining in the feed of other users. what is the best way to deleted also all activities that the users do against another user?

my first idea was to put the likes in the same feed of the event owner.in this mode when i delete a feed i can delete also all related activities because they are in the same feed. but in this case if another user follow this feed he see also all activities of other users that he not follow. and this is bad.
i read also about the foreign_id, but it is helpful to delete all activities with same id in the same feed but, in this case, all likes are in different feeds.
any help? thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there. Can you add the code that says on which feeds you're posting the likes and how you set up your follow relationships? Are you posting it on pippo's notification feed? With normal feed structure, the user who posts a like wouldn't see that activity in their own feed.

Comment: hi, now i have the same data structure of the Instagram android clone http://blog.getstream.io/best-practices-for-instagram-style-feeds/ i think that if a user post a like or a comment he must have this activity also in his feed because the followers must see this activities in their own timeline. if a user follow 100 users he can see their likes or comments only if this users copy this activities in their 'user' feed. the problem is that if i delete a user feed the activities that others users do against this still exist in their feed

Comment: Usually likes/comments would still be written to the feed of the person who authored the activity that got liked/commented, not on the feed of who did the like or comment. Unless you're doing this on purpose for discovery for your users, ie, if John liked Mary's photo, and you want John's followers to learn about Mary, but then you'd have to do a bunch of manual cleanup if you wanted to wipe Mary's feed.

Comment: exactly i want to do this for this last reason. the Instagram app have two types of activities. in the first activity you can see all activities of the person that you follow, in the second activity you can see all activities that the other persons do against you. i want to make an activity like the following activity. but i see that with getstream.io this is a easy thing only in write mode. there are lack of api for a bulk delete or for a bulk unfollow

Comment: especially in my case is very important that the followers see my likes, because the likes in truth are a retweets. They are made to be seen by others users

Comment: @DiagonalThink Did you get any solution for your scenario? I am also dealing with delete with propagation case *(including like, comment, mentioned users in comment)*. Could be helpful for me..

Comment: no sorry, i left :)